# PHP insert into SQL statement with several parameters

Tags: php, mysql

i have a simple php INSERT INTO SQL statement that simply refuses to update several columns at once. i have no idea why but the following statement is acceptabel;

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO niceTable (first) VALUES ('Hello')";
```

however if i try to following

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO niceTable (first, last) VALUES ('Hello', 'You')";
```

it breaks down and throws the following error:

"Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc) VALUES ('Hello', 'update')' at line 1"

I have checked the syntax, but it seems ok. I am using a one.com server. Anyone got any tips?

Comment: What's the output from `DESC niceTable`?

Comment: I suggest you find the correct SQL statement. The one that is actually reporting the error rather than just any randon SQL statement in your code. The letters `desc` dont appear in your example code

Comment: the error message you posted along with the column names, do not reflect the question

Comment: i switched the names of the column naturally to reflect an example. other answer got the question and answered it

Comment: Ok. well am glad that this was resolved. @Saucepan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actual query (not the one in your question) seems different. The error message seems to have `desc` somewhere, which is a reserved word. If you use reserve words as column names (don't), you should enclose them in backticks:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (`order`, `desc`) VALUES ('foo', 'bar');
```

Comment: I upvoted this because you noticed the actual column name OP  is *really* using. Good catch Bart.

Comment: oh, i had no idea there was reserved words. i updated it and changed the word, and it worked! thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

As per your "posted code":

The reason being that `first` and `last` are MySQL reserved words

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

and require special attention.

Either wrap them in ticks or rename them to something other than reserved keywords.

```
INSERT INTO niceTable (`first`, `last`)
```

**Edit:** However, your error doesn't support the issue here, nor the column name(s):

> for the right syntax to use near 'desc)

this tells me you are using `desc` which is also another MySQL reserved word.

You should also use prepared statements

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Plus, should your inputs contain characters that MySQL may complain about such as apostrophes `John O'Neil` then you will need to escape those values.

MySQL will interpret that as `('Hello', 'John O'Neil')` in turn causing another syntax error.

Escaping it, would interpret it as `('Hello', 'John O\'Neil')` making it valid.

- *I'm thinking ahead here*.

Comment: thank you for the elaborate answer! i am planning to use prepared statements, however at this point i just wanted to establish the connection :). cheers!

Comment: @Saucepan you're welcome, glad to have been of help. *Cheers*

Answer (score 1):

Enclose your column names in backticks

Last is a function in MySQL

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO niceTable (`first`, `last`) VALUES ('Hello', 'You')";
```